# Why is my QPushButton closing the application in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

```
from sys import (exit, argv)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QPixmap, QFont)
from random import choice

#Word list for the words the user will attempt to guess
words = ['Captivity', 'America', 'Europe', 'Federal', 'Gluten', 'Ridiculous', 'Automatic', 'Television', 'Difficult', 'Severe', 'Interesting', 'Indonesia', 'Industrial',
     'Automotive', 'President', 'Terrestrial', 'Academic', 'Comedic', 'Comical', 'Genuine', 'Suitcase', 'Vietnam', 'Achievement', 'Careless', 'Monarchy', 'Monetary', 
     'Quarantine', 'Supernatural', 'Illuminate', 'Optimal', 'Application', 'Scientist', 'Software', 'Hardware', 'Program', 'Colonial', 'Algorithm', 'Intelligent']

#Creates the main widget which will contain everything else
class hangman(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #Creates the QLabel 'background' which will contain the white background
        self.background = QLabel(self)
        #Uses QPixmap to place the background into the QLabel 'background'
        self.background.setPixmap(QPixmap('background.jpg').scaled(201, 352, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.background.move(0.5, 0.5)

        #Creates the QLabel 'image' which will contain the image of the hangman
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        number = '1'
        #Uses QPixmap to insert the image of the hangman into the QLabel 'image'
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_' + number + '.png').scaled(100, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.image.move(60, 0.5)

        #Chooses random word from list 'words'
        word = choice(words)  
        #Creates a blank version of the chosen word 
        blank_word = ''
        for i in word:
            blank_word += '__ '
        blank_word.rstrip()
        guessed_letters = []

        self.blank_word_label = QLabel(blank_word, self)
        self.blank_word_label.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.blank_word_label.move(0,200)
        self.blank_word_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Check', self)
        #Selects the font/font size for the label on the QPushButton 'btn' using QFont
        self.btn.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 20))
        #Creates a tooltip when user hovers over the QPushButton 'btn' using QToolTip
        self.btn.setToolTip('Click to check if the entered letter is in the word')
        #Selects the font/font size for the QToolTip above on the QPushButton 'btn' using QFont
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        #Connects the QPushButton 'btn' to the function 'check_letter' to activate when the button is clicked
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.check_letter)
        self.btn.resize(102, 43)
        self.btn.move(99, 228)

        self.entered_letter = QLineEdit(self)
        font = self.entered_letter.font()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.entered_letter.setFont(font)
        self.entered_letter.setMaxLength(1)
        self.entered_letter.setToolTip('Enter a letter and check if it is in the word')
        self.entered_letter.resize(100, 43)
        self.entered_letter.move(0.5, 228)

        #Sets where on the screen the window will open and the size of the window respectively using x and y coordinates
        self.setGeometry(1390, 30, 200, 270)
        #Locks the size of the window and make it impossible for the user to change it
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Hangman')
        #Sets the window icon to the image file 'icon.png' located in the same folder as the source file
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))      
        self.show()

    def check_letter(self):
        if self.entered_letter.text() in word:
            guessed_letters.append(self.entered_letter.text())

        else:
            number = int(number)
            number += 1
            number = str(number)
            self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_' + number + '.png').scaled(100, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
            QApplication.processEvents()

        blank_word = ''
        for i in word:
            if i in guessed_letters:
                blank_word += i

            else:
                blank_word += '__ '

            blank_word.rstrip()

        self.blank_word_label = QLabel(blank_word, self)
        QApplication.processEvents()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Begins the execution of the QApplication

    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = hangman()
    ex.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the Hangman game I am currently working on. It is being created using PyQt5 and Python 3.5 on a Windows 7 32-bit machine. The problem I am having is that when I click the QPushButton 'btn' the application closes and I can't figure out why. It isn't finish and there is a lot of code missing but I think it has what it needs to do what I want it to do but it doesn't work. Any help/advice is welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the variables you create in a method only exist in that area, for example word only exists in initUI, but you want to use it in check_letter, so that's why your program crashes. I have corrected those errors and besides correcting some of the logic, another error is that you are creating a new QLabel, instead you must update the text.

```
class hangman(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #Creates the QLabel 'background' which will contain the white background
        self.background = QLabel(self)
        #Uses QPixmap to place the background into the QLabel 'background'
        self.background.setPixmap(QPixmap('background.jpg').scaled(201, 352, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.background.move(0.5, 0.5)

        #Creates the QLabel 'image' which will contain the image of the hangman
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.number = 1
        #Uses QPixmap to insert the image of the hangman into the QLabel 'image'
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_{}.png'.format(self.number)).scaled(100, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.image.move(60, 0.5)
        #Chooses random word from list 'words'
        self.word = choice(words)  

        #Creates a blank version of the chosen word 
        blank_word = '__ '*len(self.word)

        self.guessed_letters = ""

        self.blank_word_label = QLabel(blank_word, self)
        self.blank_word_label.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.blank_word_label.move(0,200)
        self.blank_word_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Check', self)
        #Selects the font/font size for the label on the QPushButton 'btn' using QFont
        self.btn.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 20))
        #Creates a tooltip when user hovers over the QPushButton 'btn' using QToolTip
        self.btn.setToolTip('Click to check if the entered letter is in the word')
        #Selects the font/font size for the QToolTip above on the QPushButton 'btn' using QFont
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        #Connects the QPushButton 'btn' to the function 'check_letter' to activate when the button is clicked
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.check_letter)
        self.btn.resize(102, 43)
        self.btn.move(99, 228)

        self.entered_letter = QLineEdit(self)
        font = self.entered_letter.font()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.entered_letter.setFont(font)
        self.entered_letter.setMaxLength(1)
        self.entered_letter.setToolTip('Enter a letter and check if it is in the word')
        self.entered_letter.resize(100, 43)
        self.entered_letter.move(0.5, 228)

        #Sets where on the screen the window will open and the size of the window respectively using x and y coordinates
        self.setGeometry(1390, 30, 200, 270)
        #Locks the size of the window and make it impossible for the user to change it
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Hangman')
        #Sets the window icon to the image file 'icon.png' located in the same folder as the source file
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))      
        self.show()

    def check_letter(self):

        if self.entered_letter.text() in self.word:
            self.guessed_letters += self.entered_letter.text()
        else:
            self.number += 1
            self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_{}.png'.format(self.number)).scaled(100, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))

        blank_word = ''
        for i in self.word:
            if i in self.guessed_letters:
                blank_word += i
            else:
                blank_word += '__ '

        self.blank_word_label.setText(blank_word)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. Also thank you very much the corrections and optimization. : )